# Can I know how to pass the zend session in /docs folder?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, zend-session, php, zend-session-namespace

I have wordpress blog in /docs folder, I would like display zend session data on blogs header page. so I would like identify the zend session in wordpress header file, can any one tell me how do it?

Comment: Nothing in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+zend-framework

Comment: $_SESSION not working for you?

Comment: I have tried with $_SESSION is logged in function, still it showing an session identity as false.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use the `Zend_Session` code in your wordpress header.php file?  Eg:

```
    require_once $ZendFolder.'/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    Zend_Session::start();
```

Comment: Thanks chris, I have tried this one. still i will try again on monday tanx for response

Comment: Ok.  What happened when you tried this?  Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Zend_Session_Exception: Session must be started before any output has been sent to the browser; output started in ,,,

Comment: when I tried with different options including your case as well giving me error. any way thanks for you concern chris. I have implemented  using zend rest client it is working fine now.

Comment: @Guru can you show me the code you used to get zend sessions into wordpress please or check my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052538/get-zend-sessions-in-wordpress thanks